# calling another route for the return value

Tags: php, silex

hello I am new to silex and what I try to do basically is

I have one controller that uses curl to fetch something from another server. Then I have a different route where I want to show something specific from that value(JSON) returned.

I thought of using something like

```
$app->get('books', function() use ($app) {

    $content = $app->get('overview/books/');

   $content = json_decode($content);
   return ... ;
})

$app->get('overview/books', function() use ($app) {

    // do the curl operation and return

})
```

but obviously that doesn't return what I want.. How can I solve this?

Comment: You may want to abstract away the json-getting code to a service, and call that from both controllers.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your json-getting code in a service and use that in both controllers.

First, you should create a class that will contain all your relevant code:

```
class JsonFetcher
{
    public function fetch()
    { /* your code here */ }
}
```

then register it as a service:

```
$app["json-fetcher"] = $app->share(function () {
    return new JsonFetcher();
});
```

Then use it in your controller:

```
$app->get("books", function () use ($app) {
    $fetcher = $app["json-fetcher"];
    $json = $fetcher->fetch();

    // your code here
});
```

Edit:

If your service would be a one-method class, and it has no dependencies, you may simply register a function as a service like this:

```
$app["json-fetcher"] = $app->share($app->protect(function () {
    //fetch and return json
}));
```

You can read about `share` and `protect` in the [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) docs.

Comment: thanks I got the point here.. the only thing I have problems with where do I leave my own classes? and would it also be possible to do it without registering it as a service? so just $json = new JsonFetchet(); ?

Comment: Where it seems fit in your project structure :) in silex there's no fixed project structure. Yes, you can get away with instantiating it in your controller, but it's best practice to use a service for it. Also, I'll edit my answer in a few minutes for the simplest way to create services.

Comment: Thanks for that then a service it is. I have no problem with that tbh I tried it this way now but somehow it says can't find the JsonFetcher class.. I think I have issues with my structure. I'll keep it to the first solution because maybe I'll extend it with more methods later.

Comment: could you help me out with this please. Somehow the class is not found. How can I be sure that its findable? I put it in composer already and generated new autoload.

Comment: I believe that's worth another question.